# Show that Then $B'$ is a basis $\iff $ the matrix $P = \{[v'_{1B}],\ldots,[v_{nB}]\}$ (The $B$ coordinates of $B'$ vectors) is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, over a field $K$, of dimension $n$. Let $B = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ be a basis  and $B' = \{v'_1,\ldots,v'_n\}$ be a set of $n$ elements in $V$.

Then $B'$ is a basis $\iff $ the matrix $P = \{[v'_{1B}],\ldots,[v_{nB}]\}$ (The $B$ coordinates of $B'$ vectors) is invertible. I am having difficulty with the backwards direction.

Suppose that $P$ is invertible. I am stuck with not much insight on how to proceed. Hints appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by B coordinates of B' vectors?

Comment: Suppose you want to show that $B'$ spans $V$. Take any element $v\in V$. Use the basis $B$ to write $v=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i$. Now since $P$ is invertible $Px=[v]_B$ has a solution $x$. Show that $[v]_{B'}=x$, hence $v$ can be written as linear combinations of vectors in $B'$.

Comment: In proper MathJax usage, $P = \{[v'_{1B}],\ldots,[v_{nB}]\}$ is between a single pair of dollar signs.  You shouldn't repeatedly alternate in and out of MathJax in the course of writing that expression.  See my edits to the question. (And $v'_{1B}$ is coded as v'_{1B}.) $\qquad$

Comment: @user9077 how do you show that Show that $[v]_B′=x$

Comment: $[v]_B=Px=\sum x_i[v_i']_B=[\sum x_iv_i']_B$. Hence $v=\sum x_i v_i'$.

Comment: @user9077 you are treating the components of $x$ as scalars ?

Comment: $x=[x_1\,x_2\,\cdots x_n]^T$